# ubuntu compatible macbookpro11.5?

Tags: macbook-pro, macbook-air

my macbook pro 11.5 el capitan is compatible ubuntu ? 
Informations matériel :

```
Nom du modèle : MacBook Pro
Identifiant du modèle : MacBookPro11,5
Nom du processeur : Intel Core i7
Vitesse du processeur : 2,5 GHz
Nombre de processeurs : 1
Nombre total de cœurs : 4
Cache de niveau 2 (par cœur) :  256 Ko
Cache de niveau 3 : 6 Mo
Mémoire :   16 Go
Version de la ROM de démarrage :    MBP114.0172.B07
Version SMC (système) : 2.30f2
Numéro de série (système) : C02QM4VEG8WP
UUID du matériel :  DB224F20-0576-5D22-AC07-3D80CFF14C58
```

merci beaucoup

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring that you seem to have given up with English after the first sentence, I'll explain a bit about Ubuntu.

***You should never have to worry whether or not your computer will run it as long as it is a somewhat recent model and contains somewhat well-known hardware***

Since Macs generally have very generic hardware (HPs are almost exactly the same for some reason), they generally work pretty well with Ubuntu. I believe, however, that there is a rather advanced step you need to take, involving the installation of a third-party bootloader (or whatever the name is -- I'm too tired to remember).

Most people recommend [installing rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html#osx), but I personally prefer the [Clover bootloader](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cloverefiboot/), which is very easy to install and supports booting from Mac, Linux and Windows, and even hybrid boots of legacy and EFI. (It's also highly themeable)

[Here's a handy guide to installing Ubuntu using rEFInd](http://www.howtogeek.com/187410/how-to-install-and-dual-boot-linux-on-a-mac/). If you want to try out Clover, ignore the instructions involving the rEFInd installation and just install Clover instead.

To directly answer your question, yes, your computer should work perfectly fine with Ubuntu.

Comment: merci beaucoup and sorry my english is not very good. what version of ubuntu is best for my macbook  ?  thank very much

Comment: @AlainIphon I would get 15.10. It isn't LTS, so it won't be supported very long, but the update process when 16.04 comes out won't be hard, and 15.10 has some new stuff that 14.04 doesn't.

Comment: 17.10 works fine as well on that model.

Answer (score 1):

Alain, I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS in my macbook pro 11,1 without any issues, but only after doing a few minor tweaks. See the bottom of this page, where it lists a few extra tweaks on top of those needed for 12.04 LTS:

http://albert.rierol.net/ubuntu-12.04-LTS-macbook-pro.html

Overall, I have been using ubuntu in macbook pro models since Ubuntu 6.06 LTS, without ever any significant issues. Battery life has always been *better* than with MacOSX, and performance too (generally far less swapping or none at all).